# Windows crashes when Installing RX 470 Drivers on Windows 10.

Tags: windows, drivers, 64-bit, amd-graphics-card

I got an MSI Rx 470 4GB. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

**I have tried (in every case the computer rebooted while installing)**

- I have tried installing: 16.7.1, 16.7.2, 16.7.3, 16.8.1, 16.8.2, 16.9.2, 16.10.1
- Installing drivers via windows update.
- CCleaner Registry
- DDU with nvidia, amd and intel
- Only connecting one display

**Specs**

- Motherboard: ASRock H81M-VG4 R2.0
- 8GB memory
- Intel Pentium G3250 3.2GHz
- 650W power supply
- Windows 10 Anniversary Update

Comment: Have you ran windbg to determine the reason for the crash?

Comment: No, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing a fresh copy of Windows pre-anniversary update.